# Multi router setup...best approach

Tags: networking, lan, wan

I'm trying to figure out the best way of setting up my network. I've got internal wiring to various points in the flat. As such, the topology is somewhat limited. I have 2 routers - a netgear n300 and a tilgin hg2301. The tilgin is provided by the ISP, and it has to be the first point of entry from the external line in order for internet to work. Here's what I have:

1. The external line is connected to the tilgin on the WAN port.
2. A cable is connected to a tilgin lan port that goes into the wall, and comes out in the room with the netgear. That is connected to the netgear WAN port.
3. Both currently have DHCP enabled. As of now, all devices are connected to the netgear, and wifi is disabled on the tilgin. The tilgin is giving out ips like 192.168.1.139 (that's the ip the netgear gets). The netgear is giving out ips like 10.0.0.1.
4. All of this is working fine; however, I now need to add another router to extend the network to another room. And even this would be no problem, except the fact that there's a media server on the netgear, which I need to be able to access from devices connected to the tilgin and the new router.

I've tried connecting the cable that's going into the netgear WAN to a netgear LAN. This allows the devices on the tilgin and netgear to see each other, but internet doesn't seem to work anymore. It's be great if I could do this with the minimal changes possible... i.e. connect the wall cables to netgear and new router's WAN ports, devices to LAN ports and have the devices on the routers see each other. Is this possible?

Comment: You need to completely re-think the configuration you're using... to be able to access the media server you'll either need to write some rules in the routers (probably impossible with the SoHo setup you're using)... OR, turn off the DHCP settings in your "secondary" routers/access points. What you SHOULD do: Keep the Tilgin as the MAIN modem/router (use this as the sole DHCP server in your network) -> connect all routers using their LAN ports to the Tilgin LAN ports -> static IP addresses for your secondary routers (but keep within your Tilgin subnet) -> disable DHCP of your secondary routers

Comment: Thanks. Would that allow a "secondary" to be the wireless connection point? due to the location of the tilgin, it makes it a pretty bad wireless endpoint (it's behind a thick wall).

Comment: Just tried what you said, and it works. It does take away one of the four lan ports. Is there any way of having the connection from the primary go to the WAN port, but treat it the same as a LAN port? [probably a silly question...]

Comment: Not unless you flash the router firmware with one that may allow turning the WAN port into an additional LAN port. Unfortunately, yes, you lose a LAN port but you're using SoHo devices thata aren't designed for many devices. With the setup I've suggested above, yes, you can chain pretty much as many devices you want/need to expand your network - dependant on number of physical ports and IPs you have in your subnet range.

Comment: I don't understand the -1 for this question. I can imagine there are a lot of users with tge same/similar questions. +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are over-complicating your network setup.

You should only ever have one DHCP server for such a small network. You should, also, have one range of IPs for all your devices to be able to communicate together without special routes that allow your devices to talk to each other across different subnets.

A suggested solution to your network would be:

1. **Plan your network** - draw it on paper if necessary. Where is your DHCP device? What is your gateway? (both are your Tilgin). What IP range are you going to use? (it's easier to stick with the Tilgin's range - it'll probably be 192.168.1.x) - this will allow you to work out any static addresses you may (will) need).
2. Use your Tilgin modem/router as you currently do (as it was supplied by your ISP) but ensure it is the only DHCP server device on your network.
3. Configure the Tilgin DHCP pool (how many devices will it serve). A suggestion may be 192.168.1.10 to 192.168.1.240 - giving you 230 possible devices that can obtain IPs automatically.
4. Disable DHCP functionality on all your "secondary" routers
5. Configure your "secondary" routers and/or access points to have static IP addresses just outside your DHCP scope but within the subnet of your network. For example, Netgear router 1 192.168.1.2, new router 2 192.168.1.3 etc etc. - Alternatively, you could use your Tilgin modem/router to "reserve" IP addresses for your "secondary" router devices - this can often help with managing your addresses so you don't duplicate if you extend your network further in the future.
6. Configure your "secondary" routers to have their gateway and subnet as your Tilgin IP and subnet - don't forget, they are now (technically) clients of the Tilgin just like your computers and other devices are.
7. Connect your "secondary" routers and/or access point devices to your Tilgin modem/router
8. Configure the "secondary" routers' and/or access point wifi settings so that each one is the same as the Tilgin - this will allow seemless roaming across your network.
9. Test your network

Comment: Thanks for the detailed steps. For the wifi bit, do I need to anything to configure the secondaries as repeaters, or is simply having the same SSID / pass / security settings enough?

Comment: Just make sure the settings are the same for each router/AP and you'll be fine. The complicated part is understanding the IPs and getting the routers configured into "bridge" or "access point" mode so everything can talk to one another.

Comment: Ok...so I have tilgin as master, with the same wifi settings as the netgear, netgear connected using LAN port. Devices on tilgin can see those on netgear and vice versa...even with wifi. That should work the same way with another router. Quite happy...wasted hours on this on various days and gave up. Thanks, Chris. 
Lastly...assuming the "bridge" and "access point" stuff is working properly as all connections are working. Or is that a separate step?

Comment: If you add another router to your network then it should make no difference what port you plug it into (just make sure you never use the "WAN" port on any device). The important thing is to make sure you give the router itself a static IP and then turn off DHCP. Netgear are pretty good for this as they have plenty of support. "Bridge mode" is another way some routers turn off DHCP. An "Access point" is a special device that doesn't have DHCP capability but these are often expensive - hence why people tend to re-use existing routers.

Comment: Ah...thanks for the explanation...and all the help.