# Port binding and how to use it when setting up a secondary router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wan

I am trying to understand what my WAN settings should be and how my ports should be bound for the following setup:

Context:
I have a main router (let’s call this "sky") on the first floor, but the signal is not strong enough on the second floor, so I am adding a second router HG533 to the setup.

I have an Ethernet cable running from the sky router to the HG533 into the LAN 4 port. I have set up the sky router on IP address 192.168.1.1 and the HG533 router on 192.168.1.2.

I have enabled DHCP server for both.

It seems to be working fine, but the WAN port binding features were trial and error and am not sure if what I have done is correct.

Here’s what my current settings look like:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi router setup...best approach](https://superuser.com/questions/859572/multi-router-setup-best-approach)

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the DHCP Server on the Second Router and you will be good to go. 2 DHCPs can cause IP Address Conflicts, and also The Second DHCP of the Second Router will give as gateway its self. In your case 192.168.1.2. What you need is the DHCP from the First Router which will give the gateway 192.168.1.1 which is the router with the internet access. No more configuration is needed after that.

You don't need bridging or something like that, you just need a repeater. Not a second router.

If you want now to extend the WLAN Signal with the same SSID what you have to do is configure both routers with the same SSIDs same Encryption (WPA2-PSK both for example) same Password, and broadcast on different channels. Preferably one away from the other (1, 5 for example)

If you don't want them to have the same SSID then you just set a different ssid on the second one, and pick whatever channel you like, or let the router decide "auto".

Comment: But... Bridging _is_ what repeaters do. It's not a routing function.

Comment: Ok, so I will switch off the DHCP on the second router and set the routers on separate channels. But what are these port binding settings (see image) doing? When I was playing about it seemed that having them not ticked sometimes led to no internet connectivity. Or are they not really of use for what I am trying to do in which case can I untick everything?

Comment: So in your first router which communicates directly with your ISP, you should let either the PPPoE or the IPoE , intact, and if you have other services like VoIP, IPTV and remove any bridge connection setup.
On your second router just remove everything you don't need them. 
After you terminate the DHCP from your second router, all the clients connected to it will take gateway and ip from the first router, so they will use your second router as a mean to connect to the first one through your ethernet cable. 

I haven't played with the Bridging, many users have. This setup however will work.